# Rerender inputField on Lightning component (dependent picklist hack)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rerender, dependent-picklist, forceinputfield

Is it possible to re-render an inputField in Lightning so that it re-fetches its values from the server (how we used to do it with VF)?

I am well aware of the limitations associated with picklists and in particular dependent picklists, so I am trying to see if it is possible to fetch the corresponding options by re-rendering the field (as opposed to describing the field, getting the values, and setting them on the page).

One idea I had was to use the `valueChange` event on the master picklist:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.record.MasterList__c}" action="{!c.rerenderPage}"/>
```

However I am not sure what to write for the action handler.

Comment: WIth the re-render you mean? I am not sure if I am on the right path at all here, but I have a valueChange handler that I don't know what to do with. I know how to assign values to my DOM elements when a change occurs, but I don't know how to re-render a field on the page so that it dynamically fetches its values from the server.

Comment: Here is the main thing, @Mossi2, most of us here won't just write code from scratch for you. However,  If you have an idea and get stuck, post your progress and we'll likely get you moving.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I am not sure if I needed a code from scratch. What I was hoping was "hey what you are trying to do is not possible because of X" or "this is possible; you just need to do Y and the fields on the record will get re-evaluated and reset"